# order by: if two or more result match with limit 1 then randomize

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT * FROM my_database ORDER BY priority DESC LIMIT 1
```

my_database:

```
 name | priority 
##################
 dave |   100
 pat  |   100
 jo   |    99
```

1: What's the deciding factor when there's two possible results and the limit is set to 1?

2: Can you add randomization between the two possible matches? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1: What's the deciding factor when there's two possible results and the limit is set to 1?

Unless we specify ordering by a primary key (or a combination of fields to make it completely clear to the DB how to order), we cannot predict which of the two possible results will display. Database engine will determine that.

I tried the query (Example: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e2df77/2) `SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY priority DESC LIMIT 1` and Pat showed up. Then I tried `SELECT * FROM test where priority = 100 ORDER BY priority DESC LIMIT 1` and Dave showed up. Moral: don't count on the results unless you tell the database unambiguously how to order information.

> 2: Can you add randomization between the two possible matches? How?

You can order your query using `RAND()`.

```
SELECT * FROM test where priority = 100 
ORDER BY priority DESC, RAND() DESC LIMIT 1
```

A variant of above can be used for randomization. `order by rand()` or `order by field, rand()` will work.

Example: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e2df77/3

Answer (score 2):

If you want to randomize between the highest priorities, then use:

```
ORDER BY priority DESC, rand()
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: To extend this answer a little bit... without a specific ordering criteria, the result is not deterministic. There is no guarantee which of those will be returned. But we do observe some behavior that appears to be repeatably consistent (based on the position of the rows in the index or table). So the result isn't truly random. There's just *no guarantee* which row will be returned. To get a random result, add another expression to the `ORDER BY`, as Gordon shows in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. You will only get 1 result, the other one will be discarded. The one who appear on top will be selected, the rest will be discarded.
2. Yes you can randomize and still limit to get 1 result but it will throw away the `ORDER BY priority DESC` part. You only need to make the query into `SELECT * FROM my_database 
   ORDER BY RAND()
   LIMIT 1;`